# indoor navigation and tracking people using BLE

Tags: android, ios, navigation, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Is there a way to use bluetooth 4.0 and beacons to create in-store navigation?

I am searching for the best way + API to use, for indoor tracking and navigation using `Bluetooth 4.0`. I know that you can detect if a person is near a beacon or entered the store but I am not sure if you can actually track this person and understand exactly where is he inside the store, using his phone.

Is there a way to do that, and if so what is the best tool to use it?

I also found [indoo.rs](http://indoo.rs/) but I don't know how accurate is it and if it is the best tool to use.

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's two solutions from indoo.rs:
- "proximity" - low-budget, room-level accuracy
- "fingerprinting" - 2-5m accuracy

You can purchase a demo kit here: http://indoo.rs/iosversion/

If you happen to be around Vienna, Austria we'd love to show you a live demo at our office!

PS: I still work for indoo.rs ;)

Comment: do you know about other solutions that compete with your company?

Comment: http://redpin.org/ https://www.gimbal.com/ http://www.csr.com/products/138/sirfstarv-architecture-and-sirfusion-platform

Answer (score 0):

Already since 2006 there are suppliers like infsoft (www.infsoft.com) providing indoor positioning and navigation solutions i.e. for airports or trade fairs. The technology is mostly based on WiFi and BLE/iBeacon combined with the sensors of the smartphone. It's great to see that this topic is becoming increasingly significant.